# Dynamic access based on name in findViewById

Tags: java, android, loops

Sorry for the vagueness of the title,

Below is the trouble. I want to use the x variable to iterate through this object that uses 1 -9 values in the name, (`R.id.imageButtonx`)

```
for (int x = 1; x <10; x++)
    mm.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonx));
```

//Just to go a bit deeper. This is for Android.

I start off with a Button array and then I did this:

```
 main_Menu = new Button[] {
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton8),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton9)
        };
```

so I could do a two line foreach loop to attach the onbuttonclicklistener.

So I wondered if I could reduce the ten lines into two lines. I moved to an ArrayList. I had hoped it was something like square brackets, or parenthesis, or single quotes, or double quotes to go around the x variable but from one of the answers, it seems not possible.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: You can't do that. But if you make it an array (I don't know if that is possible with the XML layout stuff Android uses) you _can_ do `R.id.imageButton[x]`.

Comment: I'm guessing you have an XML markup that has Buttons named imageButton1 ... imageButton9.  This is not a good way to create an array of Buttons for Java.  About the best you can do with that scenario is load the Buttons individually, and add their references to an array.

Comment: Thanks for the title change.

Answer (score 4):

Java does not do textual replacement of the "x" in imageButtonx with the loop variable.

However, you could create an array of imageButton IDs, and refer to each by index.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean android

Use `Resources.getIdentifier()` like this

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("imageButton" + x, "id", null);

String s = getString(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your exact needs are, you could do something similar with a separate function that returns one of the variables depending on a parameter. Something along the lines of:

```
public Button getButton(int index) {
    switch (index) {
        case 0: return button0;
        case 1: return button1;
        ...
        default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
    }
}
```

Then you could replace your loop with something like:

```
for (int x = 1; x < 10; x++)
    mm.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.getButton(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
int[] imageButtons = { R.id.imageButton0, R.id.imageButton1, R.id.imageButton2, R.id.imageButton3, ...};
for (int x = 0; x <9; x++)
mm.add((Button) findViewById(imageButtons[i]));
```

This should work properly for you. :)

Comment: How is this significantly different from [Andy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16750600/486504)?

Comment: Hmm.. It is not. I think, we wrote the comments paralell, I was the slower one. :S